# Multiple return statements and performance in C++

Tags: c++, performance

In terms of performance, is there any reason to favour a single return statement over multiple within a function?

Consider the trivial examples below.

```
int min(int a, int b)
{
    if (a < b)
        return a;

    return b;
}

int min2(int a, int b)
{
    int result;

    if (a < b)
        result = a;
    else
        result = b;

    return result;
}

enum class Fruit { Apple, Orange, Banana };
std::string fruitToString(Fruit f)
{
    switch (f)
    {
        case Fruit::Apple:
            return "Apple";
        case Fruit::Orange:
            return "Orange";
        case Fruit::Banana:
            return "Banana";
        default:
            return "Unknown Fruit";
    }
}

std::string fruitToString2(Fruit f)
{
    std::string result;

    switch (f)
    {
        case Fruit::Apple:
            result = "Apple";
            break;
        case Fruit::Orange:
            result = "Orange";
            break;
        case Fruit::Banana:
            result = "Banana";
            break;
        default:
            result = "Unknown Fruit";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note that I realise that opinion is divided in terms of style, so I would like answers to focus on the performance aspect.

Comment: Look at generated assembly (ask your compiler to output the compiled assembly to a file). If you have optimizations on, it's very likely the assembly code has equal performance, might even be equal for simple cases.

Comment: This question seems ill-posed. In any given case, either the two are equivalent -- in which case the compiler can surely tell that, and will compile them to the same assembly -- or they are *not* equivalent -- in which case "performance" is the wrong question.

Comment: Reason to favor single return? If return value needs post-processing.

Comment: Check it out yourself here http://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: Multiple returns can sometimes mess up RVO but that wouldn't apply to these examples.

Comment: @doug, do you have an example where multiple returns would mess up RVO?

Comment: @Arunmu, I tried the link you provided and `fruitToString2` (the single return version) has significantly less code generated when using x86-64 gcc 6.2. Interesting.

Comment: @ruakh. Empirical evidence seems to suggest this is not the case.

Comment: @hyde, the results differ greatly with optimisation. Depending on the optimisation flags set, either the single or multiple return versions of the functions generate less code. I cannot, however, see a clear pattern.

Comment: @Frank Thats the interesting part. Number of assembly lines code does not always translate to performance. `fruitToString2 ` does a function call to `std::string::replace`. I wouldn't be surprised if `fruitToString` is a bit faster than `fruitToString2 `. Also, won't be surprised if they are equal in performance. That is for you to measure :)

Comment: If I am to make a guess and choose one, I will go with `fruitToString` as it can make better use of instruction cache if called within a tight loop.

Comment: If you're worried about performance why are you using strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Return or not to return, that is the question.  Is it ?**

For the first snippet, an optimizer may well generate the same code for both alternatives.  For GCC 6.2 for example ([see online compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/in0eYq)):

```
    cmp     edi, esi
    mov     eax, esi
    cmovle  eax, edi
    ret
```

And by the way, it will still be the same assembler code for:

```
int min3(int a, int b)
{
    return a < b? a:b;
}
```

Here, the performance is more related to the statistic distribution of the values:  if `a` is 99% the largest, then reverting `b` and `a` could be a couple of nanoseconds faster: because there will be one less move in most of the case.  But for most applications values are not so predictable, and the performance difference so tiny that it will never be noticed.

**The switch example**

For the switch, there are chances that the compiler uses a [branch table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table)  if there are enough values to justify the small initial overhead.  With very large list of values, a `map` will certainly provide better results using a binary search on the key.

Nevertheless here it produces a sequence of comparisons, and again, the order of the values in the switch (e.g. the most frequent first) can influence performance more than the return approach.

If you try [your snippet on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/eHSPJo), you'll find out that the direct return will produce smaller and apparently faster code.  This seems due to the `string` type that make life of the optimizer more difficult.  But I'd not bet on such situation in the more general case (for example, using `const char*` results again in the [same code for both functions](https://godbolt.org/g/CXtCa5))

**Quote of the day:**

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil - [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)